# Why logback is not logging some lines with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback

I am trying to log some lines to a log files using logback. The file is correctly created and my console output is actually written in the log file.

Then, I inserted some `logger.debug()` instructions in my code, which I don't find in my log. Why?

I am using Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    private static final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    InitializingBean myInitializer(final IdentityService identityService) {
        return new InitializingBean() {
            public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
                logger.debug("Preparing things...");
                if (someCondition) {
                    doSomething();
                    logger.debug("Done something.");
                } else {
                    doSomethingElse();
                    logger.debug("Done something else.");
                }

            }
        };
    }
}
```

`application.properties` includes `logging.file=logs/mylog.log` and this file is created.

Logback configuration is very easy and it should be correct and correctly placed (if I change this file, e.g. by introducing a log file name pattern, it works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

Why I don't see my log instructions in my log file? Is it because I am building an InitializingBean? How can I log these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to base.xml file which has root logging set at INFO level. Pls try this to get your debug logs :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<included>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</included>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add <root level="DEBUG"> and it works fine, but it is kind of too much logging. Is there a way to increase logging level to debug only for my classes?

Comment: OK I simply added logging.level.com.lh.batactiviti=DEBUG in my application properties. That was enough after understanding the issue was in base.xml