# Unable to log to console as well as in file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

HI here is my logger class

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

```
public class PropertyLogger {


    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.prasad.logging");
    public static void debug(String message) {
        logger.debug(message);

    }
}
```

Here is my application .properties

```
logging.file=logs/prasad.log
```

This my logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name=" org.prasad.logging" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

 </configuration>
```

This not looging any thing either in console / in file

Comment: Can an extra space here `=" org.prasad.logging"` be the problem?

Comment: Also, Spring Boot logs to console and file by default, you don't really need a custom `logback-spring.xml` file

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934633/why-logback-is-not-logging-some-lines-with-spring-boot

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev i need log back configuration as i need to change logs at run time

Comment: @pvpkiran i got the following error when followed the given link            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@2:11 - no applicable action for [included], current ElementPath  is [[included]]

Comment: You have a space in the logger name in the config. I use logback (but not with spring) and the config file can be named either logback.xml or logback-test.xml. Do you also have logback-classic.jar somewhere in the classpath?